# my audio file keeps getting outdated

Tags: javascript, html

So im making a game and I am trying to make it more immersive by adding some audio. The only problem is when I implement the audio, after a while it will not play anymore and when i look at the error in the DevTools console it looks like this: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`. My browser in chrome. This also happens with links to other websites. Please help.

```js
var woodOut = document.getElementById("woodOut");
var wood = 0;
var woodbtn = document.getElementById("collectWood");
var woodFile = new Audio('https://e.edim.co/120160553/kWewWnUA8Uv9r8Ym.mp3?response-content-disposition=filename%3D%22chopping_wood.mp3%22%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27chopping-wood.mp3&Expires=1482405575&Signature=jhI4RQ50M9OKN4De2xINypM0Y7Q65IHbvasUeCkUL0Vj7ufjdFj6QogQD9t9K7HlHVC0JY7pbmyFIKUA-kxQnOAxJtp8PD0UkIKHHnr9y9asDOdpRIzFI2TzEqSX1Mz9Bg9S2OrlQe6G7Mr3yxa56XpQBLSxbswlKlC4UlxO8w3RyhSja5J2JWVtkjFZkV7m08gwv-EFVYAzgQXJ0fELy4qVdzTu~EOeuEjO0bDIbflMQUY51AeIoheXGej2FckJfwM9TWMysB5UE9i4FKKjczIy-O0nCtRAnPl5SAO-0tE-IrOVtQUIHNFV~0LVOcxCmcWA~wX42538owQVdf1gmQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJMSU6JYPN6FG5PBQ');

woodbtn.addEventListener("click", collect);

//updates woodOut
setInterval(function(){
  woodOut.innerHTML = wood;
}, 1);

function collect(){
  wood += 1;
  woodFile.play();
}
```

```html
<button id="collectWood">Collect Wood</button>
<p id="woodOut"></p>
```

Comment: Considering you have some strange URLs with expires parameter I'd assume you're using some service for the audio. Why not put it into a regular server? Assuming that's the problem.

Comment: I'm using a facebook like website. Thats probably why. Can you give me an example of a "regular server"?

Comment: Any regular web hosting service in the world, for example

Comment: would the microsoft cloud (one drive) work?

Comment: It's not a regular web hosting service. It might work, most likely not.. Why the desire to use services that are not meant to host web things for this?

Comment: Its what my school uses and has 1 terribite of storage. Even know i dont usually use it no matter how much the school tells me to lol. But i figured maybe i could store an audio file inside the cloud copy the url and use it? I'll test it but other wise i'll just look for something on google. Thank you for your help :)